# How to use external mic but internal speakers?

Tags: sound, headphones, microphone

My new laptop has only one hole for for earphones and it works for both mic and earphones. There's something wrong with the internal mic so I want to use the earphones like an external mic along slide the in-built speakers. But as soon as I plug in the earphones the in-built audio option in sound settings is gone.

I don't want to use the earphones for listening. How can I force Ubuntu 16.04 to play sound from in-built audio after plugging in my earphones?

Comment: Check out this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171082/how-to-use-both-built-in-speakers-and-external-microphone-on-a-single-jack

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to your hardware but on my laptop it appears that plugging in something on the headphone jack disables the speakers. This is on an HP pavilion laptop; result from `lshw -C sound`:

```
description: Audio device
product: FCH Azalia Controller
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
version: 01
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
```

I used the pulseAudio volume control program to view audio devices. As a test, I set some music playing out of the speakers. PulseAudio shows this playing through the "built-in audio analogue stereo" device. [Moving to the output devices tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4ZrT.png) we see the built-in analogue stereo has some options. [After putting in some headphones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkGA0.png) the options have changed. I can manually switch the port back to the speakers, but no sound came out of the speakers.

So, it seems that this isn't possible to do because the drivers for my speakers/headphone jack don't allow it. Alternate drivers may fix this, but I can't confirm that.